# Registry for javascript functions that get called on page load (including AJAX calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a specific variation on a question that seems to have been asked a few times, apologies if the answer is already out there.

I have a standard website with a menu bar and a large content div.  There are many javascript functions that I want to run every time the page is rendered, that is - after the initial load AND on any ajax call that updates the central content div.

I understand that I need to call them on the 'success' part of the ajax call - but what I'm trying to avoid is a huge list of calls all in one place.  I have about 30 javascript files and I want to keep them separated and not dependent on each other.

What I'm trying to set up is a central "function registry" - this is what I have so far -

```
var rebind = function(){

    var functions = [];

    var add = function(f){
        functions.push(f);
    }

    var call = function(){
        for (i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
            functions[i]();
        }
    }

    return {
        add: add,
        call: call
    }
}();
```

Here is how I call this function -

```
$(function() {
    rebind.call();
});

$(document).on("click", "a.ajax-content", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("div#content").load(url, function() {
        rebind.call();
    });

    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here's an example of how I register a function, using Datepicker as an example.

```
rebind.add(function() {
    $(".dm-type").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm",
        changeYear: false,
        changeMonth: true
    });
});
```

Just to clarify, I use $(document).on('click'... when I can.  This method is simply for functions that need to be called after the page is loaded.  A global version of document.ready that also handles AJAX calls.

It seemed like a good idea, but it's not working 100%.  I'm getting some infinite loops, with jquery-raty for instance.

Has anybody come up with a good solution for this?  I looked into livequery, it didn't handle everything I needed and I read that it's not advised because it can slow things down.  If there's an easy solution to this it would help me a great deal.

Thanks!
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different technique as you are already using jQuery - delegation!

Attach a custom event to your body and use that as a listener, that was you can create multiple function calls and even manage which calls are triggered from there.

```
 //in a global file    
 $(document.body).on('myCustomEvent',function(event, data){
    //console.log(event,data);
    //manage your function calls here.
    //You can pass data through and have your logic here too.
    if(data.somedata || data.someotherdata) datepicker();
});


//in a singular file
$(document).on("click", "a.ajax-content", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("div#content").load(url, function() {
        $(document.body).trigger('myCustomEvent', [{somedata:true}]);
    });
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You could also attach the listener to the body in all your separate script files and each trigger fire by any script will trigger it in all other scripts etc.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly.  No more infinite loops and the code is much cleaner as a result.